# how to fix C++ runtime error : addition of unsigned offset

Tags: c++

```
string removeDuplicates(string s) {
    for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){
        int count = 0;
        while (s[i-count]==s[i+1+count])
            count += 1;
        i -= count;
        s.erase(i+1,2*count);
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    return s;
}
```

You are given a string s consisting of lowercase English letters. A duplicate removal consists of choosing two adjacent and equal letters and removing them.

We repeatedly make duplicate removals on s until we no longer can.

Return the final string after all such duplicate removals have been made. It can be proven that the answer is unique.

This is leetcode problem 1047. My code is running in vscode but i'm getting error when i submit this.
Please help if you know the error.

```
Line 1065: Char 9: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x7ffd301f5600 overflowed to 0x7ffd301f55ff (basic_string.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:1074:9
```

Comment: The translation of the error message is that you are using an index of -1 to access `s`.

Comment: "My code is running in vscode but i'm getting error when i submit this." thats because you are not testing it properly when running it locally. Try to cover the edge cases: empty string, string with only duplicates, etc...

Comment: and because of the address sanitizer which is enabled on leetcode but perhaps not when you run it locally

Comment: If `i-count` always a positive number? Is `i+1+count` always less than `s.length()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens with this string `"aa"`.

First `i` and `count` equal zero so `s[i-count]==s[i+1+count]` is true, so you execute `count += 1;`.

Now `i` equals zero and `count` equals one and again you check `s[i-count]==s[i+1+count]` but this time `i-count` equals `-1` so you are checking `s[-1]` and that is illegal and leads to the error message you see.

Maybe `s[i-count]` is a typo for `s[i+count]` but even with that change I don't think your program is correct.

What you need to do is think a lot more carefully about the code you write. Every time you write `X[Y]` you must always think whether `Y` could be too big or too small for `X`. It's not enough for it to be correct most of the time, it has to be all the time.